# Adding two variables in one column in ssrs report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am building a report in SSRS and the point is, i have a column in which i need to display two variables, the variable a and variable b, how should i do it?

Should i create an expresion like this:

```
a.value + "/" + b.value
```

How should i do to display the value of a, only if the value of b is empty?
something like:

```
`IF (a.value = NULL) , display b.value`
```

Any help is appreciated, i know it's something easy to do but i don't have much experience with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `IIF` expression:

```
=IIF(Fields!a.Value Is Nothing,Fields!b.Value,Fields!a.Value)
```

or, if you want to combine values:

```
=IIF(Fields!a.Value Is Nothing,Fields!b.Value,Fields!a.Value & "/" & Fields!b.Value)
```

Comment: thank you very much, could you please explain me what they do? the second one, displays b if a is empty?

Comment: `IIF` function is a one-liner for `IF-THEN-ELSE`, so if expression in the first argument evaluates to true, then it returns value of it's second argument, else it returns value of the third argument.